# Issue while positioning HTML/CSS elements

Tags: html, css, alignment, move, web-frontend

I need your help guys,

I tried `float` I tried `display:inline-block` and nothing work.
They keep moving like they want not as I want if u know what I mean.

So how should I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code pls

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` property. This can give your expected result. At first wrap all your `div` elements with a single `div`. Then set that parent div's display to flex. No need to use `absolute` position.

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="child-left">Left side contents</div>
    <div class="child-right">Right side contents</div>
</div>

.block {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
}
```

To know more about `flex`, check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions. Please also see: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.block2{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
}
.block3 {
  height: 400px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
    <div class="block1 block"></div>
    <div class="block2 block"></div>
    <div class="block3 block"></div>
```

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions. Please also see: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)